# In XMLHttpRequest, where is error flag variable?

Tags: javascript, w3c, xmlhttprequest

In the [XMLHttpRequest Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#error-flag) it says that:

> The DONE state has an associated error
>   flag that indicates some type of
>   network error or abortion. It can be
>   either true or false and has an
>   initial value of false.

Also says something similar about a "send() flag" in an "OPENED" state.

It's said in the specification but not in the IDL and when I create a new XMLHttpRequest I can't find those "flags".

Where are those boolean variables?

Comment: Any reason you are working at this low of a level? certainly jquery or similar will give you better results.

Comment: @Byron Whitlock, jQuery ajax is just a wrapper of the Ajax calls, and I agree, it gives you better error results.

Comment: You both are right, at the end I will use jQuery and I don't even need to use those "flags" but I like to know what is happening underlying although I will finally be using jQuery for all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I [wrote](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webapps/2010JanMar/0915.html) to the webapps e-mail list about those flags, this is what [they responded](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webapps/2010JanMar/0919.html):

> Everything that authors can use is
> expressed in the Web IDL fragment.
> Everything outside of that represents
> some kind of data implementations need
> to keep around one way or another to
> properly implement the specification.

(That was my doubt)

Answer (score 5):

The `XMLHttpRequest.readyState` property is what you're looking for.

From the Spec you've given, you will see that all those "boolean" flags are actually numeric values.

- **UNSENT** (numeric 0)
- **OPENED** (numeric 1)
- **HEADERS_RECEIVED** (numeric 2)
- **LOADING** (numeric 3)
- **DONE** (numeric 4)

These values are the result of `XMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange` event handler.
Basically, in order to get those values, do something of this effect.

```
//In Javascript
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
if (request) {
  request.onreadystatechange = function() { 
    if (request.readyState == 4) { //Numeric 4 means DONE

        }
   };

request.open("GET", URL + variables, true); //(true means asynchronous call, false otherwise)
request.send(""); //The function that executes sends your request to server using the XMLHttpRequest.
}
```

Bear in mind, always write the `onreadystatechange` event **BEFORE** calling the `XMLHttpRequest.send()` method (if you decide to do asynchronous calls). Also, asynchronous calls will call `XMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange` event listener so it's always vital you have that implemented.

More info on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xmlhttprequest)

Comment: +1 for mentioning that you have to define onreadystatechange before calling send.  Common pitfall.

Comment: Thanks for the information, it's neat and clear.

I knew this, what I was wondering is if you have access to those "flags" directly in the object, what I wanted to know was more for sureness than for applicability (it's kind of useless, I know). Sorry if I wasn't clear in the question.

I also wrote to the w3c webapps e-mail list, I'll put that on a new answer.

Answer (score 4):

I've heard that the XHR editor said that the error flag referenced in the spec is an internal implementation variable that consumers cannot access.

Same deal with the "send()" flag.

Comment: Thanks, I wrote to the editor some time ago and got the answer, it's what you wrote. I'm sorry I hadn't tag that answer as the accepted one.